# Set timestamp of container to apply in docker logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to see logs of container with timestamps but timezone of the logs are not set from `ENV`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Tehran
```

But after building the container using`docker-compose up -build` and running the command below to see logs of container, I see the timestamp is not set properly for `Asia/Tehran`:

```
docker-compose logs -ft api
```

Comment: The timestamp in the logs is output by the Docker daemon, not the container. So you can't change it by setting the TZ in the container. I don't know if it's possible to change for the daemon. It seems to output in UTC by default.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/683651/827162

Comment: @gohm'c I've tried that solution but no success.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible. The output of the timestamp in the logs when you run `docker logs -t` or `docker-compose logs -t` comes from the docker client which is forwarding the logs from the docker engine. Looking at the [code for including the timestamp](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/10aecb0e652d346130a37e5b4383eca28f594c21/api/server/httputils/write_log_stream.go#L50-L52):

```golang
        if config.Timestamps {
            logLine = append([]byte(msg.Timestamp.Format(jsonmessage.RFC3339NanoFixed)+" "), logLine...)
        }
```

The `msg.Timestamp` field is not passed through [`time.Local()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Local) so it should always be treated as UTC, no matter the timezone of the host running the docker engine, or the client calling the docker API.

The timezone of the container doesn't apply here unless you add the timestamp to your logs of your application itself and skip passing the `-t` option.

Answer (score 0):

The base image that you used is important. Here's a quick out-of-the-box example:

```
docker run --init -d --rm -e TZ=Asia/Tehran centos bash -c 'while true; do echo "$(date) INFO log message."; sleep 1; done'
docker logs -f <container>  # you will see the log date time uses container's TZ instead of the host
```

[image]

You can change the TZ to different timezone to see different log date time. If you include "-t" in the logs command, you will see the host date/time prepend to your log message.